# Subject 'complete' of rxjs is not unsubscribing on complete - Angular

Tags: angular, memory-leaks, rxjs, unsubscribe

Subject 'complete' of rxjs is not unsubscribing on complete in Angular.

I am using the 'takeUntil' unsubscription approach.
I have multiple subscriptions in my app and I would like to unsubscribe all of them in 'ngOnDestroy'.

I have created the following logic:

```html
@Component({
  selector: "app-example",
  templateUrl: "./example.component.html"
})
export class Example extends onDestroy { 

  private unsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject();

  // ... some subscriptions: 
  // observable.pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)).subscribe(/* do something */)

  ngOnDestroy() {
     this.unsubscribe.next();
     this.unsubscribe.complete();    
     
      if (this.unsubscribe.closed) {
        //subscribed
        console.log("unsubscribed");
      } else console.log("subscribed");
  }
}
```

and it logs to the console "subscribed".

**the only operator I'm using in all of the pipes is 'takeUntil'.**

Should I use '.unsubscribe' instead of '.complete'?

Comment: This approach is fine

Comment: it seems that `closed` property is [always](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Subject#closed) `false`

Comment: @vitaliykotov When I tried it with ‘.unsubscribe’ instead of ‘.complete’ in the ‘ngOnDestroy’ it logged ‘unsubscribed’, I thought .complete is supposed to unsubscribe as well eventually

Comment: `unsubscribe()` method is used to dispose saved subscription, f.e. `const subs = this.unsubscribe.subscribe(); subs.unsubscribe()`. When passing it to `takeUntil` you just should emit some value (`unsubscribe.next()`) to terminate the stream. And it's just a good practice to `complete` the Subject